# Give an example of an algebra on a set E such that A does not separates points of E and A vanishes at some points of E.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

One example I know is $f(x)=f(-x)$. I want another example with explanation.

Comment: What do you mean by "Algebra A on a set E"?

Comment: It is a temptation for new Community members to post Questions in which the only problem statement is confined to the title, and to use the body of the Question only for editorial remarks.  Please edit your Question to give a fuller (self-contained) problem statement in the body of the Question, so that Readers can better appreciate the context of those editorial remarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the algebra of polynomials in $\sin x$ with constant term equal to zero, defined on the set $E=\mathbb{R}$. (In other words, $A$ contains all functions $f$ such that $f=p(\sin x)$ for some polynomial $p$ whose constant term is zero.) It is clear that $A$ doesn't separate integer multiples of $\pi$, and in fact it vanishes at those very points.